# IOS IBAction button not going to website using URL

Tags: ios, xcode, nsurl, ibaction

i have a button on a view controller and i want to click the button and it goes to a web site.
the website is held on parse.com.

the code as follows

```
- (IBAction)WebAddressBtn:(id)sender {
    NSString *url = [self.exam objectForKey:@"Website"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    NSLog(@"website: %@",url);
}
```

the `NSLog` shows Null for the value url

but the data is held at

```
self.exam objectForKey:@"Website"
```

NSLog confirms its there

this works and will go to google

```
- (IBAction)WebAddressBtn:(id)sender {


    NSString *url = @"http://www.google.com";
    //[self.exam objectForKey:@"Website"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    NSLog(@"website: %@",url);


}
```

if i try

```
NSURL *url = [self.exam objectForKey:@"Website"];
```

url is still showing as Null
but i know the data is in self.exam objectForKey:@"Website

NSLog Output for data

```
    name = "DMK Media & Photography Ltd";
    phone1 = 01993835148;
    phone2 = 07795966848;
    postcode = "OX28 4BT";
    products = "<PFRelation: 0x10dc75320>(<00000000 00000000>.(null) -> products)";
    website = "http://www.dmkmedia.co.uk";
```

Comment: Did you check the value of [self.exam objectForKey:@"Website"];. Please log this in your question.

Comment: May be you call `self.exam` before you add object to it. Alternatively if `self.exam` is NSMutableDictionary check you initialised it before calling `-setObject:forKey:`

Comment: What do you mean, it's "not going to website"? Safari doesn't open? It goes to the *wrong* site? Please be as specific as possible.

Comment: What is the type of `[self.exam objectForKey:@"Website"]`? Is it possible that it’s already an `NSURL` instead of an `NSString`?

Comment: its not doing anything but if i hard code htt://www.google.com in to it then it will go to google

Comment: Check spelling of key "Website" instead of "website"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL wont work properly if it doesnot have properly formatted url. Please check whether your url has "http://"

Comment: is it possible for you to paste the url here? or hardcode the url http://www.google.com and see whether it works.

Comment: so it confirms that url is not correct, we cant help you further without seeing your URL. :)

Comment: NSlog Output now in main post with url

Comment: website spelling is wrong? W is small case. Is that the issue?